# How to connect search form to database and retrieve data on Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, search-form

I am trying to connect my search form to my database and retrieving data from there. But something is going wrong. My controller or my routes... But I couldn't figure it out.

the problem is it's showing the data directly without, searched.
I want to see the data when I search. Also try to search and this is coming:

```
Collection {#221 ▼
  #items: []
}
```

My view is here:

```
<form action="{{URL::to('welcome')}}" method="post" role="search" class="searchbox">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <input type="text" name="q" class="search" placeholder="町, 地域, 会社名, 物件名">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="search">
  </form>
  @if(isset($details))
      <p> here is the results <b>{{$query}}</b> are : </p>
    @endif
<table cellspacing='0'>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>会社名</th>
    <th>物件名</th>
    <th>住所</th>
    <th>販売価格</th>
    <th>専有面積</th>
    <th>間取り</th>
    <th>竣工時期</th>
    <th>入居時期</th>
  </tr>
  <thead>
  <tbody>
  @foreach($estates as $estate)
    <tr class="even">
      <td>{{$estate->company_name}}</td>
      <td><a href="{{json_decode($estate->link)}}" target="_blank">{{$estate->name}}</a><br/></td>
      <td>{{$estate->address}}</td>
      <td>{{$estate->price}}</td>
      <td>{{$estate->extend}}</td>
      <td>{{$estate->rooms}}</td>
      <td>{{$estate->old}}</td>
      <td>{{$estate->entery}}</td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Also here is the controller and my route.
What am I doing wring here?

```
public function welcome()
{

    $estates = Estates::orderBy('price')->get(); 

    $data['estates'] = $estates; 
    return view('welcome', $data);

}

public function search(Request $request)
{
    $q = $request->q;
    if ($q != " "){

        $estates = \DB::table('estates')->where("name","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
            ->orWhere("address","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
            ->get();

        dd($estates);

        if(count($estates) > 0){
            return view("welcome", compact('estates'))->withQuery($q);
        }

    }

    return view("welcome")->withMessage("No Found!");
}
```

Here is route:

```
Route::get("/", "PagesController@welcome");

Route::post("/", "PagesController@search")->name('search.route');
```

I couldn't figure it out. Also first controller `welcome` retrieving data smoothly without search form! But I want it to run when I try to search. Any help? Thank you!

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Can you show us the route you defined?

Comment: try to write welcome in quotes

Comment: @FrankerZ  added the error message mate.

Comment: @Exterminator Thanks mate, page is came but it's showing the data directly without search. I want it to show me when I searched it.

Comment: try moving to other page then came back to same page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your form action to

```
<form action="{{ route('search.route') }}" method="post" role="search" class="searchbox">
```

Change your route to

```
Route::post("/", "PagesController@search")->name('search.route');
```

Add `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` on top of your PagesController and change your controller method to

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $q = $request->q;
    if ($q != " "){

        $estates = \DB::table('estates')->where("name","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
            ->orWhere("address","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
            ->get();

        dd($estates);

        if(count($estates) > 0){
            return view("welcome", compact('estates'))->withQuery($q);
        }

    }

    return view("welcome")->withMessage("No Found!");
}
```

Comment: App\Http\Controllers\Illuminate\Http\Request does not exist this message occures when I try to search.

Comment: thanks mate, I fix that but this time here this message `"Undefined variable: estates (View: /var/www/html/laravel/resources/views/welcome.blade.php)"` thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Try this `return view("welcome", compact('estates'))->withQuery($q);`

Comment: tried your new edit, but still the same problem. Also still retrieving data on the page without search.

Comment: What's output of `dd($estates);` just before `if(count($estates) > 0)` ?

Comment: with this `$q = $request->q; dd($q);` i can return search box what I enter. with out  a problem.

Comment: but when I try to delete if(count) and return this `dd($estates);` it' running this error. `Undefined variable: estates (View: /var/www/html/laravel/resources/views/welcome.blade.php)`

Comment: I think its because of the naming of your Model. Convention is Model name should be singular and table name should be plural. Try above updated code.

Comment: okay mate :)  you fix the error and I try to search this is coming `Collection {#221 ▼
  #items: []
}`

Answer (score 0):

here you can do it this way too

change the route like this

```
Route::post("/", "PagesController@search")->name('routeName');
```

and change the form action like this

```
<form action="{{route('routeName')}}" method="post" role="search" class="searchbox">
```

or edit you code and pass the url to value in quotes

```
<form action="{{URL::to('welcome')}}" method="post" role="search" class="searchbox">
```

For more information check this [Laravel Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing)

Comment: Thanks for the help mate. I can see the page, but i can see database retrieving without search. Also when I try to search, it's going 404. something? Any help for that? I updated the codes and give the detail for problem.

Comment: don't use double quotes inside double quotes in form action.

Comment: define it the way i did. `action="{{URL::to('welcome')}}"`

Comment: try `echo 'asd'; exit();` in search

Comment: and what path is it showing in network tab of console

Comment: define your `action` like this `action="{{route('routeName')}}"`